# adding users, membership, and roles to site

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have followed scott's gu tutorial [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx)

I uploaded the whole database to my site. Before doing what Scott's says I had one username stored in the membership. How can I create an additional user now that the table is in the web host? I can see that there's aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Applications, etc..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up your own admin section of the website.

There is a CreateUserWizard control which will make creating new users really easy.

This tutorial series shows you how to setup an admin area that lets you manage user accounts:

- http://www.asp.net/learn/security/#administrativetasks

This is some tips I have picked up along the way for using CreateUserWizard:

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/search/label/createuserwizard

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS2008, there's an ASP.NET configuration option under the project menu.  Choose that and it'll open the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool.  In the securities tab, you can update/add users.

If you want to add users via SQL, take a look at the membership stored procedures.  They are prefixed with aspnet_Membership.

Comment: You cannot use the WSAT to administer remote servers so unless you have remote desktop access to your server this is not possible